# Runtime error in codeforces but worked just fine in Dev-C++

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm trying to solve a problem which requires: a sentence that has less than 150 characters as an input and makes that sentence's characters all to uppercase while removing all extra white spaces, then prints the changed sentence and its number of characters to the screen.
For example: 
Input: `Look            in to the   abyss`  
Output:`LOOK IN TO THE ABYSS:20`

 I tested this program on Dev-C++ and it worked just fine but when i submitted it to CodeForces I got runtime error. I hope anyone can help me with this.
( I tried to use scanf("%[^\n]%*c", sen) and fgets(sen, sizeof(sen), stdin) instead of gets(sen) but i still get runtime error. Also, i use a different function strlength instead of strlen since i had another type-related error when submitting that piece of code to CodeForces )
 P/s: Sorry for my bad English

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int strlength(char* str){
    int i,j = 0;
    for (i=0; str[i]!= '\0';i++)
        ++j;
    return j;
}
void strip_white_spaces(char* str){
    int x,i;
    for (x=i=0; str[i]!='\0';i++){
        if (!isspace(str[i])||((i>0) && (!isspace(str[i-1]))))
            str[x++] = str[i];
    }
    if (isspace(str[x-1]))
        str[x-1]='\0';
    else str[x] ='\0';
}
void touppercase(char* str){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0';i++ ){
        if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
            str[i] -= 32;
    }
}
void main(){
 char sen[150];
 gets(sen);
 strip_white_spaces(sen);
 touppercase(sen);
 int s = strlength(sen);
 printf("%s:%d", sen, s);
}
```

Comment: Does CodeForces provide any type of indication what was the runtime error?

Comment: Single step through the code with your favourite debugger and find out where it crashed. And note that there is no function called "gets" in the C language - it was flagged as obsolete some 25 years ago and completely removed 9 years ago. You need to get new learning material that isn't 30 years outdated.

Comment: @Yonlif : CodeForces just states that there is a runtime error, but does not indicate anything specificly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the bug ! 
The error turned out to be at 'void main()' function. 
When i replaced it with int main(), i got perfect results in CodeForces. 
Thanks everyone for helping me !

Answer (score 1):

`isspace(str[i-1])` will read out of bounds for `i == 0`, which might cause the program to crash if you are lucky. You need to rewrite that function with different logic.

Comment: I edited that line of code and have i running from 1, but even though it still worked just fine in Dev-C++, CodeForces again showed runtime error.